# Pandas tuple with value and dictionary into dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dictionary, dataframe

Currently, I have data in the following form:

ie.

```
[ ('ab', {'a' : [apple1], 'b': [ball1]}), ('cd', {'a' : [apple2], 'b':   [ball2]})]
```

List[Tuple[Any, dict{'key':List}]]

The goal is to create a pandas data frame in the following form:

```
start   a             b
ab    apple1         ball1
cd    apple2         ball2
```

I have tried to it the following way:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['start', 'a', 'b'])
for start, details in mylist:
    df = df.append({'start' : start}, ignore_index= True)
    df = df.append({'a' : details['a']} , ignore_index= True)
    df = df.append({'b': details['b']}, ignore_index=True)
```

I'm trying to figure out an optimized way to do this.

Comment: Updated with the tried code

Answer (score 3):

#### [`pd.DataFrame.from_dict`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html)

Pandas works well with a dictionary *or* a list of dictionaries. You have something in between. In this case, converting to a dictionary is trivial:

```
L = [('ab', {'a' : ['apple1'], 'b': ['ball1']}),
     ('cd', {'a' : ['apple2'], 'b': ['ball2']})]

res = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict(L), orient='index')
res = res.apply(lambda x: x.str[0])

print(res)

         a      b
ab  apple1  ball1
cd  apple2  ball2
```

Comment: What's the purpose of `res.apply(lambda x: x.str[0])?`

Comment: You have lists in your inner dictionaries, this is one way to extract the first (and only) element from each list.

Answer (score 3):

Like this:

```
form = [ ('ab', {'a' : ['apple1'], 'b': ['ball1']}), ('cd', {'a' : ['apple2'], 'b':   ['ball2']})]

# separate 'start' from rest of data - inverse zip
start, data = zip(*form)

# create dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(list(data))

# remove data from lists in each cell
df = df.applymap(lambda l: l[0])

df.insert(loc=0, column='start', value=start)

print(df)
     start     a      b
0    ab   apple1  ball1
1    cd   apple2  ball2
```

or, if you want start to be the index of the dataframe:

```
# separate 'start' from rest of data - inverse zip
index, data = zip(*form)

# create dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(list(data), index=index)
df.index.name = 'start' 

# remove data from lists in each cell
df = df.applymap(lambda l: l[0])

print(df)
start     a      b
ab   apple1  ball1
cd   apple2  ball2
```